# Putting NGINX in front of kafka

Tags: nginx, apache-kafka, nginx-reverse-proxy, filebeat

I have elasticsearch, filebeat and kibana behind NGINX server and all three of them uses ssl and basic authentication of Nginx reverse proxy. I want to place kafka behind NGINX as well. Kafka is communicating with filebeat. Is there any possible way that filebeat (with ssl) and kafka (without ssl) can communicate?

I mean is there any exception kind of thing that we can add in NGINX configuration?

Comment: I don't understand how/why Filebeat is behind Nginx when it doesn't use inbound network ports

Comment: I just realised it later on and made the correction of my theoretical concept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much benefit to using Nginx with Kafka beyond the initial client connection. In other words, yes, you can use `stream` directive, in theory, for `tcp` reverse proxy, and point `bootstrap.servers` at it, but Kafka will return its `advertised.listeners` after that, and clients then bypass Nginx to communicate directly with individual brokers (including authentication)

Related

- [Allow access to kafka via nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59050175/allow-access-to-kafka-via-nginx)